# How to call scope variable from inside a Power-Shell function?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script with couple of functions which are checking if connection to the database is okay or not. From one of these functions I want to call another function or scope, which will check am I runnning in 64bit Powershell or 32 bit. I want to switch to the 32bit version before trying to connect to the database since I was getting an error saying:

```
 Exception Message: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw 

BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components 

installed."
```

In my understanding this means I am using 32 bit version of Oracle Client and I am running in 64bit powershell.

What I am doing:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient

Function TestDatabaseConnection($connectString)
{
$rVal = 0

try
{
    Invoke-Command $CheckPowerShellVersion
    LogInfo ("  Testing database connection ....")
    $conOracle = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectString)
    $conOracle.Open()
    ... 
    ...
    }
}
catch
{
    LogError("Error in database connection test
    Caught an exception:
    Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)
    Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)")
    $rVal = 1
}

$conOracle.Close()
return $rVal
}
```

And i have the CheckPowerShellVersion scope variable like this:

```
    $CheckPowerShellVersion = {

    if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
            write-warning "Switching to 32-bit.

PowerShell."
        if ($myInvocation.Line) {
               &"$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoP -NoL $myInvocation.Line
           }
        else
           {
             &"$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoP -NoL -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
           }
         exit $lastexitcode
       }
}
```

I get the output in console **"Switching to 32-bit PowerShell."** which means it is calling it, but I also get an error saying "The term **'TestDatabaseConnection'** is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: When you are opening a new PS session, then it does not know the functions that have been loaded in the previous PS session, that's why `TestDatabaseConnection` is unknown in the new session. I recommend the following approach: At the beginning of your script, check if it is a 64-bit PS and if so, open a 32-bit PS where you call your whole script. Otherwise, keep on executing.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, the error make sense now but  I'm still confused tho. I am calling the `TestDatabaseConnection` from another PS script from where I am supplying the connection string.  In the script where `TestDatabasConnection` lives, I have just this line of code `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient` and 3-4 functions for working with the database similar to this one. You are saying to move the code above all of these functions and do the checking if it is a 64-bit PS and call my whole script inside so it can load all the functions?

Comment: Put at least all the code that has to be executed in a 32-bit PS into one script file and launch it in a 32-bit PS if it is not already running in one. You have to think about how to transfer results if you do not put all code (also the code that may run under 64-bit) in one script file. So the easiest solution would be to put everything into one script file and to make sure at the beginning of the script that it is run under 32-bit. You can use `$PSScriptRoot` to get the current directory of your script file and the relaunch it if needed.